# Verify file digital signature from kernel

Tags: c, file, kernel, sign

Can i check from kernel driver whether file signed with real certificate(like VeriSign or GlobalSign)? Do anybody have code which can do this?
Thanks!

Comment: If you intend to go down this route, note that the OpenSSL license and the GPL license are probably incompatible enough that you should _not_ move OpenSSL into the kernel, except as a toy for yourself. If you intend on distributing the results to others, you should pick a GPL-licensed cryptography toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

No. While the kernel has some support for certain cryptographic operations, it does not have a full SSL implementation (which would be necessary to verify certificate chains), nor does it have an embedded list of trusted CAs.